# Email notifications of exceptions happening in a Python app?

Tags: python, debugging, email, exception

UPDATE: This is a Django web app

Hi folks, I want to set up email notifications when there is an error happening in my application. In ruby, there is a very elegant solution called ExceptionNotifier, which wraps around the exception handler and uses the built-in mailer to send an email.

What is the best way of doing this in Python? I know that this is a very common issue, so would love for any tips that you folks can share!

PS: Code samples, pointers to modules would be AWESOME! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm guessing you're talking about a web app here, because ExceptionNotifier is a Rails plugin...)

A Python web app using which framework? I know there's [Django-hoptoad](http://bitbucket.org/sjl/django-hoptoad/src), which is actually a step above the ExecptionNotifier of Ruby, using [ThoughtBot's Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/pages/home).

But that's just a guess that you're using Django, which you might not be...

Similarly, Pylons (and by extension, Turbogears 2, I guess), has [configuration options for error emails](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/modules/middleware/)

Comment: I don't believe the OP ever stated that it's a web application.